# RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am getting the following error:

> RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression `'^/?(\\d+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)(\\.html|/)?$'\n`

Please find my htaccess configuration below:

```
RewriteRule ^/?mokuji - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^/?(\d+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)(\.html)?$ index.php?pid=$1&pkey=$2&pkey_ext=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hyphen needs to be at first or last place in a regex to avoid escaping otherwise it needs to be escaped**

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^mokuji - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([\w-]+)/([\w/-/]+)(\.html)?$ index.php?pid=$1&pkey=$2&pkey_ext=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.